# binding in wpf doesn't work, can't see why

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a wpf app I'm using some xaml code that should let me view pdf files,  I just started to use data biding and don't figure  way this not works for me.

here m XAML:

```
<Grid>
<telerik:RadPdfViewerToolBar RadPdfViewer="{Binding ElementName=pdfViewer, Mode=OneTime}" SignaturePanel="{Binding ElementName=signaturePanel, Mode=OneTime}"/>
<telerik:SignaturePanel x:Name="signaturePanel" PdfViewer="{Binding ElementName=pdfViewer, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1"/>
<telerik:RadPdfViewer x:Name="pdfViewer" DocumentSource="{Binding Path=PathOfPdf, Mode=TwoWay}"  DataContext="{Binding CommandDescriptors, ElementName=pdfViewer}" telerik:RadPdfViewerAttachedComponents.RegisterSignSignatureDialog="True" telerik:RadPdfViewerAttachedComponents.RegisterFindDialog="True" Grid.Row="2" telerik:RadPdfViewerAttachedComponents.RegisterSignaturePropertiesDialog="True" telerik:RadPdfViewerAttachedComponents.RegisterContextMenu="True"/>
<Grid>
```

And here code behind:

```
public partial class Page2 : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
     }  

private string _pathOfPdf= @"D:\MyFile.pdf";

    public string PathOfPdf
    {
        get{ return _pathOfPdf; }
        set{
            if (_pathOfPdf != value)
            {
                _pathOfPdf = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }   
}
```

If I'm not using Biding it works fine. I if I do(on XAML):

`DataContext="D:\MyFile.pdf"` it shows the pdf

Comment: what is this for DataContext="{Binding CommandDescriptors, ElementName=pdfViewer}" ?? I think if you rmove this, your binding should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either set the `DataContext` of the control or the source of the binding to the `Page` where the source property is defined:

```
<telerik:RadPdfViewer x:Name="pdfViewer"
                      DocumentSource="{Binding Path=PathOfPdf, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}" />
```

Comment: plz vote for [helpful question](https://tutorialzine.com/2015/12/the-10-most-entertaining-stackoverflow-questions-of-all-time)